# How to Get SoapHeader on JaxWS WebService

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jax-ws

I have one webservice jax-ws and i need get soap header, i make this:

```
@Resource
private WebServiceContext context;

MessageContext msContext = context.getMessageContext();
SOAPMessageContext soapMsgContext = (SOAPMessageContext) msContext;
SOAPHeader soapHeader = soapMsgContext.getMessage().getSOAPHeader();
Iterator it=soapHeader.extractAllHeaderElements();
```

but i have problem to cast MessageContext to SoapMessageContext, and i can't make SoapHandler because i can't send object from handler to webservice because to send i need put de object on Application Scope and i not want that.

Comment: You say you have a problem casting MessageContext to SoapMessageContext. What problem are you having? What is the actual type of the object returned by `getMessageContext()`?

Answer (score 2):

Don't know which version of JAX-WS you are using.

But

```
@WebMethod
public myResource(@WebParam(name = "MyHeader", header = true) String myHeader) {
...
}
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: This (myHeader) returns null

Comment: same, i got null in my project. how to get the value?

Comment: I could get the value of the header by using like this. @WebParam(header = true, name = "name of header attribute") String custId

Answer (score 0):

What header expect to receive? Since the [`javax.xml.ws.handler.MessageContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/ws/handler/MessageContext.html) is too a `Map<String, Object>`, you can print all contents:

```
import java.util.Map;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceContext;

@WebService
public class HelloWS {

    @Resource
    private WebServiceContext ctx;

    public String sayHello(String name) {
        Map<String, Object> map = ctx.getMessageContext();
        for (Object obj : map.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(obj);
        }
        return "Hello, " + name;
    }

}
```